# When did humans understand the science of hail?

Tags: science

I am asking this question intrigued by the fact that in certain religious books (mostly Arabic) it is stated that rain and hail comes from the sky (heaven) and not from Earth. They probably did not know that rain and hail comes from clouds. My question is when did many understand this fact?

Comment: After looking it over, I'm not convinced that there is even today a "science of hail". Kind of surprising, considering the damage it does in my part of the USA.

Comment: @T.E.D. I am also interesting in old age explanation of it :)

Comment: Note:  I did the google search, and this is not a trivial question.  Congratulations on a surprisingly interesting question.

Comment: regarding a recent edit, "What were some" questions are problematic....

Comment: @AaronBrick ok edited.

Comment: "it is stated that rain and hail comes from the sky (heaven) and not from Earth. They probably did not know that rain and hail comes from clouds" is about as logical as "Some people say that god brought them somewhere. They probably do not know that people can be transported in cars, trains or planes." The correlation between clouds and precipitation would be quite obvious to anyone who spends a lot of time outdoors rather than in front of a computer.

Comment: @Jan totally agree with that, the relationship must be clear but did they know that cloud is actually water and it is colder up there which condensed these vapors into rain? Because having some 'water' pouring from the sky, does not make a lot of sense to me thinking that all that water is from the clouds. I mean that science behind the rain that yes it is the cloud that is causing the rain, not the God :)

Comment: @Tiger Not sure about Arabia, but in Europe (esp in the more mountaineous parts) it is easily observable that 1) clouds and fog are essentially the same 2) there is a continuum from fog to drizzle to rain, and 3) heating a lot of water in a cold room (e.g. for cooking, washing people or washing clothes) will lead to fog

Comment: @Jan I did notice that I asked the question about hail and not rain. This article [Ice From heaven](https://historyofislam.com/science-and-faith-in-islam-relations-between/the-miracle-of-ice-from-the-heavens/) in particular is trying to make sense of 'rain/hail from heaven' which I do not agree with at all.

Comment: That article is not a historical source and it seems that for the author, the distinction between sky and heaven is not important. See the updated beginning of my answer for why this might be the case.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen a lot of rain and a bit of hail, and it *almost always* came from above, i.e. from the sky. Indeed, my country's official meteorological agency agrees that [rain](https://www.dwd.de/DE/wetter/thema_des_tages/2015/8/24.html) and [hail](https://www.dwd.de/DE/wetter/thema_des_tages/2015/7/26.html) really come from the sky or maybe from heaven ("Himmel" in German can mean both).

[Aristotle had already figured out most of the physics of rain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteorology_(Aristotle)) before 322 BCE. His works were translated into Arabic by about 800 CE and into Latin (again?) in the 12th century.

Given that the formation of (thin) fog from warm water is easily observable in many kitchens and bathrooms, and that the formation of drizzle and rain from fog and clouds is easily observable when taking a walk on a rainy day in the mountains, Aristotle may have been not the first to reach such conclusions.

Aristotle's main problem in his explanation of rain seems to have been his (lack of) understanding of chemistry, but the physics are quite sound. Clouds are some form of condensated water, water evaporates when it is warm and condensates to clouds when it is colder. When it gets even colder, the clouds will start to rain. The whole thing is a cycle.

> The exhalation of water is vapour: air condensing into water is cloud. Mist is what is left over when a cloud condenses into water, and is therefore rather a sign of fine weather than of rain; for mist might be called a barren cloud. So we get a circular process that follows the course of the sun. For according as the sun moves to this side or that, the moisture in this process rises or falls. We must think of it as a river flowing up and down in a circle and made up partly of air, partly of water. When the sun is near, the stream of vapour flows upwards; when it recedes, the stream of water flows down: and the order of sequence, at all events, in this process always remains the same. So if ‘Oceanus’ had some secret meaning in early writers, perhaps they may have meant this river that flows in a circle about the earth.

> So the moisture is always raised by the heat and descends to the earth again when it gets cold. These processes and, in some cases, their varieties are distinguished by special names. When the water falls in small drops it is called a drizzle; when the drops are larger it is rain.

His explanation of hail, however, explicitely rejects a theory (by [Anaxagoras](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaxagoras)) which is closer to our current understanding, because (paraphrasing) "hailstones are not round". However, Aristotle's discussion of a theory which he rejects also shows us that already back then an explanation for hail existed which is somewhat similar to our modern understanding: Hailstones can be formed when the clouds reach up into cold regions of the atmosphere.

> Some think that the cause and origin of hail is this. The cloud is thrust up into the upper atmosphere, which is colder because the reflection of the sun’s rays from the earth ceases there, and upon its arrival there the water freezes. They think that this explains why hailstorms are commoner in summer and in warm countries; the heat is greater and it thrusts the clouds further up from the earth. But the fact is that hail does not occur at all at a great height: yet it ought to do so, on their theory, just as we see that snow falls most on high mountains. Again clouds have often been observed moving with a great noise close to the earth, terrifying those who heard and saw them as portents of some catastrophe. Sometimes, too, when such clouds have been seen, without any noise, there follows a violent hailstorm, and the stones are of incredible size, and angular in shape. This shows that they have not been falling for long and that they were frozen near to the earth, and not as that theory would have it. Moreover, where the hailstones are large, the cause of their freezing must be present in the highest degree: for hail is ice as every one can see. Now those hailstones are large which are angular in shape. And this shows that they froze close to the earth, for those that fall far are worn away by the length of their fall and become round and smaller in size.

> It clearly follows that the congelation does not take place because the cloud is thrust up into the cold upper region.

([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20040429034002/http://etext.library.adelaide.edu.au/a/a8met/meteo1.html))

Comment: Even if in danger of ruining a possible joke via explanation: _when_ in your experience did hail _not_ come from above? When in a plane yourself flying thru some clouds?

Comment: @LangLangC when having rain together with 80 km/h winds.  At that time rhe rain was moving quite horizontally. Snow is quite similar and can even be observed to.move upwards. When walking through clouds in the Alps, I also sometimes got the feeling that the drops are just coming from all sides.

Answer (score 2):

In the Middle Ages and into the early Renaissance in Europe, hail, like [lightning](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2501/was-there-any-theological-opposition-to-the-lightning-rod) and other severe weather phenomenon, was thought to be caused by [demons in the air](http://www.miltontimmons.com/ChruchesVsLightningRod.html). Sad, but true.

From [Summa Theologica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summa_Theologica) of St. Thomas Aquinas:

> Rain and winds, and whatsoever occurs by local impulse alone, can be
> caused by demons. It is a dogma of faith that the demons can produce
> winds, storms, and rain of fire from heaven <sup>1,2</sup>

For this reason, whenever severe weather threatened, the best response was thought to be to ring the church bells or fire cannons to frighten off the demons. Sprinkling of Holy water, praying, and other such liturgical remedies were also done to try to drive the demons away.

These days some folks try [cloud seeding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_seeding) with silver iodide. Sadly, there [isn't a whole lot of evidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail#Suppression_and_prevention) this works any better than the cannons and holy water.

---

<sup>1</sup> *[See Thomas Aquinas, "Summa," pars I, qu. lxxx, art. 2, cited by Maury, "Légendes Pieuses," 11. The second citation I owe to Rydberg, "Magic of the Middle Ages," 73, where the whole interesting passage is given at length.](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Popular_Science_Monthly_Volume_31.djvu/469)*

<sup>2</sup> *[Memoryhole](http://www.memoryhole.net/kyle/2006/01/thomas_aquinas.html)*

Comment: Where in the Summa can that be found?

Comment: Also, that merely says that they *can* be produced by demons, not that the demons are the sole cause.  Arsenic in springs can be put there by malice, but can also occur naturally.

Comment: @Mary - If the point of this comment was to induce me to argue *for* the logic of this point of view, I'm afraid you're going to be sorely disappointed.

Comment: Its point was to rebut your claim, not theirs

Comment: @Mary - Pretty sure I never made any such assertion. If I did (and I'm somehow not seeing it) you are correct that its nonsense.